# Can I get help diagnosing this leak trace from LeakCanary v2.0-beta-3?

Tags: android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, leakcanary

Here is the full leak trace that I got from LeakCanary. This appears to be coming from a `fragment` that contains a `GoogleMap`. I'm confused because the `GoogleMap fragment` has no `RecyclerView` in it. The `GoogleMap fragment` is one out of three `fragments` in the `Android` app. A `RecyclerView` is used in the other two.

```
LibraryLeak(className=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, leakTrace=

┬
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
│    Leaking: NO (InputMethodManager↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    GC Root: System class
│    ↓ static InputMethodManager.sInstance
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
│    Leaking: NO (InputMethodManager is a singleton)
│    ↓ InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
│                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
│    Leaking: YES (View detached and has parent)
│    mContext instance of com.example.surfbait30.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ RecyclerView.mParent
├─ android.widget.LinearLayout
│    Leaking: YES (RecyclerView↑ is leaking and View detached and has parent)
│    mContext instance of com.example.surfbait30.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ LinearLayout.mParent
╰→ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
​     Leaking: YES (LinearLayout↑ is leaking and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
​     mContext instance of com.example.surfbait30.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
​     View#mParent is null
​     View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
​     key = 0fbb38f9-458e-4e79-a784-7e3ca197f5d3
​     watchDurationMillis = 13927
​     retainedDurationMillis = 8925
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a library leak, which means it's a known leak in the Android framework (input method manager leak). Your own code does not have any leak here.